# How to find discrete distribution function from characteristic function?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

How to find discrete distribution function from characteristic function?
I came across the problem in my assignment and I don't know how to calculate it. I know how to calculate continuous distribution function from characteristic functions.

Here is my problem:

> For $n\ge 0$, let $a_n$ be non-negative real numbers such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=1$. Show that the function
>   $$\varphi(t):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos(nt)$$ 
>   is the characteristic function of a distribution function. What is the corresponding distribution?

My attempt is to make 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos(nt) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cdot  (\exp(int)+\exp(-int))/2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp(int)P_x(n)$$
However, I don't know the following steps to calculate it.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing [Tex](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/). It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question. Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: @Close Voter: Why?

Answer (score 1):

Take $p_n =p_{-n}=\frac {a_n} 2$ for $n=1,2,...$ and $p_0=a_0$. ($\phi$ is the characteristic function of a random variable which takes the values $n$ and $-n$ with probability $\frac {a_n} 2$ and $0$ with probability $a_0$).

Comment: Got it ! Thank you very much for your help!